# Unable to create a query with inner join

Tags: mysql

```
 CREATE VIEW `list_of_parts` 
     AS select `a`.`id` AS `id`,
    `a`.`types` AS `types`,
    `a`.`clerk_id` AS `clerk_id`,
    `a`.`clerk_name` AS `clerk_name`,
    `a`.`post_id` AS `post_id`,
    ifnull(`b`.`shop_id`,`a`.`id`) AS `my_id`,
    `c`.`status` AS `status`,
    `c`.`created` AS `created`,
    `c`.`modified` AS `modified` from ((`main_store` `a` 
left join `main_store_ids` `b` on((`a`.`id` = `b`.`shop_id`))) 
left join `sub_shop` `c` on((ifnull(`b`.`shop_id`,`a`.`id`) = `c`.`id`)))
```

I want to create a query that will get the above datas with the clerk_id from the subshop table. I want to get the data if the clerk_id from the subshop is equivalent to the main_stores clerk_id. But I cannot solve how I can accomplish it with the above code.  Some samples would be great. I would love to hear from you!

```
    a = main_store  
    b = main_store_ids
    c = sub_shop  ←　this table contains a field named clerk_id
```

Comment: Give some sample data and your expected output based on that.

Comment: FYI, stopped reading when I saw the unformatted query. Make it easy for people to help you!

Comment: formatted the query.